# What is the best way to use UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two select statements `joined` by `union` in `sql`.

If either of the select statements returns a record it has to be shown in the result.

But if both the statements are returning records, I just want only 1 result shown in the result.

Please suggest the best way to do this

Comment: pls provide the query what you have tried

Comment: Or is it SQL or MYSQL?

Comment: can you describe conditions how to choose a necessary record?

Comment: `union` does exactly what you specify, because it removes duplicates.  Hence, the question is unclear and sample data and desired results are needed.

Answer (score 1):

You want to rank your results. Let's say you have a table of this year's sales and a table of last year's sales. The tables' primary key is the seller. Now you want to show one row per seller, preferably this year's sales and only if not available you'd show their last year's sales.

With

```
select seller, sales from thisyear
union all
select seller, sales from lastyear;
```

you would get both years and you wouldn't even see what is what.

With

```
select seller, 'this year' as year, sales from thisyear
union all
select seller, 'last year' as year, sales from lastyear;
```

you would see the year, but still get both years for sellers with sales in both. Some sellers would have a row for this year only, some for last year only, but some for both years, which you don't want.

So you want to take this result, but only show the better row per seller. In standard SQL you'd rank the rows with `ROW_NUMBER`. This is available in MySQL as of version 8.0. (In older versions you can emulate this with variables somehow. You'll find many examples for this on StackOverflow.)

```
select seller, year, sales
from
(
  select 
    seller, year, sales, 
    row_number() over (partition by seller order by year = 'this year' desc) as rn
  from
  (
    select seller, 'this year' as year, sales from thisyear
    union all
    select seller, 'last year' as year, sales from lastyear;
  ) data
) ranked
where rn = 1
order by seller;
```

The expression `order by year = 'this year' desc` makes use of MySQL's true = 1, false = 0.

Comment: Can you explain this briefly

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? `ROW_NUMBER`? This function numbers the rows. The `PARTITION BY` clause tells the DBMS that I want to number rows per seller. So all rows of a seller get ordered. This year first, then last year. So for sellers with only one row that row gets number 1. For sellers with two rows, this year gets number 1, last year gets number 2. In the end I only keep the #1 rows.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give the desired result what u want

```
  SELECT id, name 
        FROM tableA
        UNION
  SELECT id, name 
        FROM tableB
```

Answer (score 0):

The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.

```
Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of columns
The columns must also have similar data types
The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order

SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```